# Ubuntu failing to install on separate HDD, blank screen, flashing cursor

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, hard-drive

I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.1 desktop ISO and burned it to a bootable CD and have made a bootable USB drive using both Universal USB Installer and Unetbootin.

I have tried multiple ways to attempt the install.
Let me explain my current setup.
I am running Windows 8.1 on an SSD as my main OS. And a couple of drives with data associated with Windows. (mostly 3 TB HDD's)
I have another separate 3TB HDD completely empty (formatted NTFS at the moment). This is where I want to install Ubuntu at, on its own hard drive. I am having a lot of trouble.

I managed to get to an Ubuntu main menu only when using the ISO boot CD for some reason (USB method only takes me to the GRUB2 menu and after I select the install Ubuntu option I get a blank screen with a blinking text cursor) When I use the CD method the results end up the same, I selected "Install Ubuntu" and the keyboard flashes and I am brought to a blank screen with a flashing text cursor.

I have even removed all of my extra drives, including the Windows drive, leaving only the empty drive in and tried multiple boot procedures, but it does not want to continue the installation, just black and a white blinking cursor.

My System specifications are the following:

- OS: Windows 8.1 64-bit
- CPU: Intel Core i7 2600k
- MOBO: ASUSTeK P8z68-V PRO
- RAM: 16GB DDR3 Corsair
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680

My main concern is this: Is there a simple way to install Ubuntu on it's own hard drive and be able to boot either Windows 8.1 (on it's own drive as well) or Ubuntu upon start up?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and I see you have a similar NVIDIA graphics card, so I'll give you what worked for me:
Make sure that your CD is not corrupted, this was a big issue as well...
This answer was created by grahammechanical on the Forums:

1. At the  accessibility screen (purple person keyboard) press ENTER
2. Select your language and hit ENTER
3. On the next screen with try/install ubuntu press F6
4. Select "nomodeset" on the mini-screen in the bottom right, using the different graphics drivers.
5. Press ESC and go to try ubuntu->install ubuntu from inside the Live Session.
   Hope this worked.
   [Original Thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2233163&p=13067528#post13067528)

Answer (score 0):

Firts: In order to allow dual booting of Ubuntu with other operating systems, Uefi Secure Boot needs to be disabled in the system firmware.

The board firmware should offer a boot menu, although on some boards this may mean you need to boot into the MS OS Win 8 and cycle through various menus to turn off Uefi Secure Boot and then reboot.

You are going to boot using Uefi you must have a Fat formatted Efi System Partition, type EF00 as the first partition in /dev/sda (your ssd hddd. This partition will contain your bootloaders.

Following these steps should begin with the new dvd/usb Ubuntu live, choosing to try and once loaded the session start installation.